# How to make Fibonacci number in matrix with numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, fibonacci

I'm just started to learn Python and I have no idea using numpy library. My teacher told me to make matrix which filled with fibonacci number. Basically he wanted me to show an output like this

[[0  1  1  2  ]

[3  5  8  13 ]

[21 34 55 89 ]]

Glad for anyone who can help me

Answer (score 0):

That's a simple task.

```py
import numpy as np

# dimensions of the matrix
n, m = 3, 4

# create resulting matrix (init with zeros for convenience)
result = np.zeros((n, m), dtype=int)

# fill up first 2 elements of the matrix
result[0 // m][0 % m] = 0
result[1 // m][1 % m] = 1

# now you don't need to refer to the matrix but store 2 last
# fibonacci numbers
prevprev = 0
prev = 1

for i in range(2, n * m):
    current = prevprev + prev
    result[i // m][i % m] = current
    prevprev = prev
    prev = current

# print the result
print(result)
```

The only thing to know here is that *ith* number in the matrix is located on **i // m** row and **i % m** column (all in 0-indexation). Try experimenting with different matrix dimensions and see it for yourself. Cheers :)

Comment: Please refrain from answering poorly posed questions, as that encourages bad behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The start of the whole procedure must be a "mission statement",
i.e. how many rows and columns should have the resulting array.

They will be *r* and *c* parameters of my function.

Then the first task is to generate a list of numbers - Fibonacci
sequence, with size *r* * *c*.

And the returned value should be:

- a *Numpy* array created from this sequence,
- reshaped to *(r, c)*.

The code to do it (the function) can be:

```
def Fibon(r, c):
    seq = [0, 1]
    for i in range(r * c - 2):
        seq.append(sum(seq[-2:]))
    return np.array(seq).reshape((r,c))
```

When you call it:

```
Fibon(3, 4)
```

you will get:

```
array([[ 0,  1,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  5,  8, 13],
       [21, 34, 55, 89]])
```